# Qual é o modo mais eficiente para implementar GroupBy em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, group-by

Estou tentando implementar um `GroupBy` com estes parâmetros

```
function GroupBy(keySelector, elementSelector, comparer)
{
    // keySelector = function(e) { return e.ID }
    // elementSelector = function(e) { return e.Name }
    // comparer = { Equals: function(a,b) { return a==b }, GetHashCode:... }
}
```

Entretanto eu não sei um modo eficiente de implementar isto.

[Eu criei um teste no jsPerf aqui](http://jsperf.com/js-groupby-complex) com `linq.js` e um método que criei que não utiliza um `comparer`, logo este só funciona em tipos 'normais'. ([Teste destes métodos aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/BDQ4k/))

Outras bibliotecas como `underscore` e `Lo-Dash` não tem o parametro `comparer` então a implementação deles não é relevante.

A chave de cada grupo pode ser até uma classe, preciso de um `comparer` para saber se o valor da chave é igual entre objetos.

Basicamente estou tentando copiar o C# Linq `GroupBy` [documentado aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Exemplo de entrada:

```
var arrComplex =
[
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Bar" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Bar" }
];
```

Exemplo de saída (ou algo assim):

```
[
    {
       "Key": {"Value":10},
       "Elements":["Foo","Bar"]
    },
    {
        "Key": {"Value":20},
        "Elements":["Foo","Bar"]
    }
]
```

Alguma ideia de como implementar isto?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer comparar se keySelector (que é igual ao id de um elemento) é igual ao elementSelector (que é o name de outro elemento)?

Comment: Basicamente estou tentando copiar o `GroupBy` do `c#` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx . `keySelector` é o que vai extrair a chave de um objeto para ser a chave do grupo. `elementSelector` é o que vai extrair o objeto a ser colocado na lista de elementos do grupo.

Comment: Então você quer criar um array associativo, é isso?

Comment: @KennyRafael O group by faz isso, `var arr= [{ Chave: 1, Valor: 2}, { Chave: 1, Valor: 3}]`... Agrupando o resultado fica `[{ Key: 1, Elements: [2,3] }]`. Tambem poderia ser um array assosiativo... `{ 1: [2,3] }`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui implementar desta forma:

Primeiro preciso de uma forma de pegar o HashCode dos objetos.

```
Object.prototype.GetHashCode = function () {
    var s = this instanceof Object ? JSON.stringify(this) : this.toString();

    var hash = 0;
    if (s.length === 0) return hash;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + s.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return hash;
};
Number.prototype.GetHashCode = function () { return this.valueOf(); };
```

Agora meu `GroupBy` ficou assim

```
function GroupBy(a, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer)
{
    // seta os valores padrões para os parâmetros opicionais
    elementSelector = elementSelector || function(e) { return e; };
    comparer = comparer ||
        {
            Equals: function(a,b) { return a==b },
            GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
        };

    var key, hashKey, reHashKey;

    // agrupa elementos pelo hashcode
    var hashs = {};
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // para caso do hash ser igual, mas retornar false no Equals
        reHashKey = undefined;

        // obtêm a chave do objeto
        key = keySelector(a[i]);
        // pega o hashcode do objeto
        hashKey = comparer.GetHashCode(key);

        // se o hash já existe na lista
        // compara os valores com Equals
        // caso retorne falso, gera um hash unico
        if (typeof hashs[hashKey] !== "undefined")
            reHashKey = comparer.Equals(key, hashs[hashKey].Key) ? hashKey : hashKey + " " + i;

        // se foi gerado um hash novo, utiliza-se esse
        if (typeof reHashKey !== "undefined" && reHashKey !== hashKey)
            hashKey = reHashKey;

        // pega ou cria um grupo e adiciona os elementos
        hashs[hashKey] = hashs[hashKey] || { Key: key, Elements: [] };
        hashs[hashKey].Elements.push(a[i]);
    }

    return hashs;
}
```

Para testar

```
var arrComplex =
[
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Bar" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Bar" }
];
//

var x = GroupBy(arrComplex
        , function(e) { return e.N; }
        , function(e) { return e.Name; }
        , {
              Equals: function(a,b) { return a.Value == b.Value },
              GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
          }
);
//

console.log(x);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Bup/1/)

Mas, [de acordo com meus testes](http://jsperf.com/js-groupby-complex), a minha implementação do `GroupBy` é mais lenta que a do linq.js. Só é mais rápido quanto converto o resultado para um array.

Resultados do teste

```
Nome                         op/s
---------------------------------
GroupBy                   163,261
GroupByToArray            152,382
linq.js groupBy           243,547
linq.js groupBy toArray    26,309
```

Comment: Tem certeza que você não está comparando maçãs com laranjas? O seu `GetHashCode` por exemplo é terrivelmente ineficiente (e à primeira vista, incorreto), o método "linq" está fazendo uso dele? Se o seu método estiver usando ele, e o linq não, isso explicaria a diferença de performance...

Comment: Esse método `GetHashCode` eu copiei de alguma resposta no Stack Overflow, eu não sei como implementar isto, como seria mais eficiente?

Comment: Pra começar, é importante que o `GetHashCode` seja **coerente** com o `Equals`: se o seu `comparer` diz que duas chaves são iguais se os `Value`s são iguais, o hash da chave (de acordo com o `comparer`) só deve fazer o hash de `Value` - não do objeto inteiro. Por que? Simplesmente porque dois objetos com o mesmo `Value` e alguma outra propriedade diferente teriam hashes diferentes mas o mesmo valor. Quanto a um método de propósito geral para fazer hashes de qualquer objeto, precisaria de um tempo pra pensar em algo, mas converter pra JSON e fazer o hash disso não me parece uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 5):

Muitas bibliotecas que implementam `GroupBy` colocam como requisito adicional que a entrada já esteja **ordenada por chave**. Uma ordenação por chave é `O(N*log(N))`, mas uma vez realizada é possível agrupar listas de qualquer tamanho rapidamente, em `O(N)`, pois basta comparar a chave de um elemento com a chave do último grupo encontrado:

```
function GroupBySimples(a, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer)
{
    if ( a.length == 0 )
        return [];
    elementSelector = elementSelector || function(e) { return e; };
    comparer = comparer ||
        {
            Equals: function(a,b) { return a==b },
            GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
        };

    var ultimaChave = keySelector(a[0]);
    var ultimoElemento = { Key: ultimaChave, Elements: [elementSelector(a[0])] };
    var ret = [ultimoElemento];
    for (var i = 1, n = a.length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        var key = keySelector(a[i]);
        if ( comparer.Equals(key, ultimaChave) )
            ultimoElemento.Elements.push(elementSelector(a[i]));
        else {
            ultimaChave = keySelector(a[i]);
            ultimoElemento = { Key: key, Elements: [elementSelector(a[i])] };
            ret.push(ultimoElemento);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

var arrComplexOrdenado = arrComplex.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.N.Value - b.N.Value;
});
var resultArray = GroupBySimples(arrComplexOrdenado
        , function(e) { return e.N; }
        , function(e) { return e.Name; }
        , {
              Equals: function(a,b) { return a.Value == b.Value },
              GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.Value.GetHashCode(); }
          }
);
```

Como você pode observar nesse [teste de performance](http://jsperf.com/js-groupby-complex/2), esse método é mais de `3x` eficiente que as alternativas apresentadas (usando hashes).

Notas:

1. Eu aumentei o tamanho do array de entrada de `4` para `100.000`, pro teste ficar mais relevante.
2. Você tem certeza que o `linq.js` está produzindo um resultado correto? A performance dele continuou mais ou menos a mesma, **com uma entrada vinte e cinco mil vezes maior**, alguma coisa só pode estar errada...